# saturn-datepicker beginDateSelectedChange reset problem

Tags: javascript, angular

The my setup is:
The user click one day and the week is selected (from Monday to Sunday). When click other day of week this reset week and re-click day for select week.
The bug is when the user (after clicked the day and selected week) re-click the same day or day in week selected, the saturn fire (beginDateSelectedChange) and this work badly.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9jy8nn

NOTE: i don't konow because stackblitz don't work with momentjs. So you must try in local for try work example

Answer (score 0):

TEMPORARY SOLUTION:
I Added SCSS/CSS attributes on root style (style.scss)

```
.mat-calendar-body-selected {
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

.mat-calendar-body-begin-range:not(.mat-calendar-body-end-range) {
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

.mat-calendar-body-end-range:not(.mat-calendar-body-begin-range) {
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

.mat-calendar-cell-semi-selected {
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
```